# Is there any replacement of dependencyManagement.importedProperties in Gradle 5?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I need to get a property like "jackson.version" from a BOM similar to org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-dependencies. I know I can do this with io.spring.dependency-management plugin by using dependencyManagement.importedProperties. But what is a way to this with Gradle's 5 Maven BOM support?

This is an example with io.spring.dependency-management(Kotlin DSL):

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Greenwich.RELEASE")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.group:artifact:${dependencyManagement.importedProperties["spring-cloud-aws.version"]}")
}
```

I'd like to do the same with Gradle 5:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Greenwich.RELEASE}"))
    implementation("org.group:artifact:${?["spring-cloud-aws.version"]}")
}
```

How to get "spring-cloud-aws.version"(any property from the BOM)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently no. There are many features that are not yet available. You can plan to see it implemented in later versions of Gradle or more likely an equivalent functionality.

See this detailed video below on the comparison of Spring Dependency management and Gradle 5's support for importing BOMs:

[Managing Dependencies for Spring Projects with Gradle by Jenn Strater and Andy Wilkinson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AADeX1AEmzU)